# Read a dsv file with custom delimiter into R

Tags: r, delimiter, read.csv

I have a dsv file with the custom delimiter `|`. I can easily read this into Stata by using the GUI to select a custom delimiter, but all the variants of `read.csv` that I've tried in R haven't worked.

Does anyone know how to how to import a dsv file into R with a custom delimiter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use: `read.table(filename,sep="|",header=TRUE)`. Given the file `sample.csv` with contents:

```
a|b|c
1|2|3
```

The output looks like:

```
read.table("sample.csv",sep='|',header=TRUE)
  a b c
1 1 2 3
```